# Parsing literal assignments from a Python file

Tags: library, python, parser

Sought: A Python 3 library (hopefully also supporting Python 2) that takes a Python file containing assignments of literal values (specifically, anything parseable by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) to variables and returns a `dict` of the resulting namespace.  If the file contains any non-literal assignments, the library either raises an error or ignores them.

For example, the library should be able to turn a file like this:

```
foo = 42
bar = [{"quux": None, "glarch": True}]
foo = 'reassigned'
```

into the value:

```
{
    "bar": [{"quux": None, "glarch": True}],
    "foo": "reassigned"
}
```

and a file like this:

```
foo = range(42)
bar = 2 + 2
quux = input()
glarch = 'Hi!'
```

would either produce an error or end up as just `{"glarch": "Hi!"}` without actually running the `range()` or `input()` (Bonus points if it can parse the `bar = 2 + 2`, though).

(I could've sworn I'd seen a library like this before, possibly as part of Django, but I can't find it anymore.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a library for this specific task, but it's easy to do it with `ast.parse`. Here's an example in Python 3:

```
import ast

with open("myfile.py", "r") as o:
    src = o.read()
top_level = ast.parse(src)

result = {}
for statement in top_level.body:
    assert isinstance(statement, ast.Assign)
    assert len(statement.targets) == 1
    name = statement.targets[0].id
    result[name] = ast.literal_eval(statement.value)

print(result)
```

If the input is:

```
 foo = 42
 bar = [{"quux": None, "glarch": True}]
 foo = 'reassigned'
 bing = 1 + 1
```

Then you get:

```
{'bing': 2, 'foo': 'reassigned', 'bar': [{'glarch': True, 'quux': None}]}
```

Comment: I did not expect the code to be that simple.